# x$name is NOT equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]], why not?

Tags: r

R Documentation (Extract {base}, Extract or Replace Parts of an Object) states that

> x$name is equivalent to x[["name", exact = FALSE]]

However

```
> s <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
> s$a
Error in s$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> s[["a"]]
[1] 1
> s[["a", exact = FALSE]]
[1] 1
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with a quote from the same documentation page:

> `$` is only valid for recursive objects, and is only discussed in the
>   section below on recursive objects.

Recursive objects are objects that can contain objects of the same type, e.g., lists or expressions.

You have taken the quote in your question out of context. It is in the section "Recursive (list-like) objects" and not in the section "Atomic vectors". You are subsetting an atomic vector.

Here is a corrected example that also illustrates the effect of `exact = FALSE`:

```
l <- list(ab = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
l$a
#[1] 1
l[["a"]]
#NULL
l[["a", exact = FALSE]]
#[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the patience, I guess I am having a hard time interpreting the documentation. Mind a few follow up questions?


How come "Applying $ to a non-recursive object is an error" ? What does it mean for an index to be computable?

Trying to understand https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: I do not understand the follow up question. The documentation is very clear: You can only use `$` for recursive objects. Consequently, `$` throws an error for all non-recursive objects. Note that `$` is mainly a convenience operator intended for interactive use.

Comment: I was asking about the underlying algorithm that makes $ work because I thought that with that knowledge I could try to understand the importance of an index to be computable and what it means for an index to be computable.

Comment: Ok I got it!

`> name <- "foo" # applying "foo" to name`

`> x[[name]]  # we can ask for name and get "foo", it was computed`

`[1] 1 2 3 4`

`> x$name     #  $ takes name as is, not computing it to "foo"`

`NULL            # so $ doesn't work.`

`> x$foo`

`[1] 1 2 3 4`

It weirdly took a while, but it finally settled in my brain. Thanks for the help btw.